# Unable to debug XSLT in Visual studio 2017

Tags: xml, visual-studio, debugging, xslt

I have an xml document along with the XSLT schema loaded into VS 2017.  When I try to debug it, I receive this error in my output window:

### XslLoadException

XSLT compile error.

### WebException

Unable to connect to the remote server

### SocketException

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The code window for the XSLT underlines the `xsl:stylesheet` in red:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:abcd="urn:abcd" exclude-result-prefixes="abcd">
```

When I place my cursor over the error it says

> Unable to connect the remote server

I am thinking that the XSL transform link needs to be updated to a new definition.

Comment: XSLT debugging is available in the Visual Studio Team System and the Professional Edition. Please make you are using the Visual Studio Edition.

Comment: I have upgraded to from Visual Studio professional 2017 desktop to the yearly subscription, just recently.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635600/visual-studio-2015-xsl-debugging-transformation-failed-webexception-socketexcept