# visual studio 2019 xslt debugging enable document function

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt

I'm debugging in Visual Studio Professional 2019 in admin mode.  I'm trying to XSL transform (xslt) that uses the document function but the UI is reporting "Execution of the document function is prohibited"  "use the xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction" to enable it.  I've searched settings but I cannot find any such setting.

[image]

Comment: Do you get debugging to work if you use code in C# and the constructor `new XslCompiledTransform(true)` together with the needed `XsltSettings`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Xsl_XslCompiledTransform__ctor_System_Boolean_ describes the conditions necessary to have VS step into XSLT code in more detail. I don't know whether there are any GUI settings.

Comment: this isn't dotnet, its just the VS built in transform feature under the Xml menu item.  I'll post a image of it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398101/358574) I fixed this in VS 2015 and forgot how I did it, but thankfully I documented the fix.  You have to be in VS folder mode.  If you're in web project mode then you don't get the document function.